# How to Synchronize two folders using web Logic bridge concept

Tags: weblogic

We are trying to synchronize two folders available in two different server locations. How can we synchronize that two folder using web logic Bridge concept or any other concept using web Logic Server. If any one have an idea about this scenario, please help us.

Thanks In Advance.
Venkat